# Wrong output in simple c++ program implementing copy

Tags: c++

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class test{
    int a,b;
    public:
    test():a{0},b{0}{}
    test(int,int);
    void copy(test);
    void print();
};
test::test(int a,int b){
    a=a;
    b=b;
}
void test::copy(test obj)
{
    a=obj.a;
    b=obj.b;
}
void test::print()
{
    cout<<test::a<<" <========> "<<b<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    test t1(4,15);
    t1.print();
    test t2=t1;
    t2.print();
}
```

The above code should print 
4 <========> 15
4 <========> 15

but it is printing
1733802096 <========> 22093
1733802096 <========> 22093

I am not getting the problem.
if I change the parameter name in the constructor it is giving correct output.
What could be the reason for such behavior??

Answer (score 2):

You are reassigning your parameters here:

```
test::test(int a,int b){
    a=a;  // You just set parameter a to its own value!
    b=b;
}
```

is not the same as:

```
test::test(int a,int b){
    this->a=a;
    this->b=b;
}
```

and should be replaced with:

```
test::test(int a,int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
```

all together.

Comment: Some people use special naming convention to avoid this type of errors in C++ code. Most common is starting all data members with "m_" prefix. Example : `struct { int m_data*; int m_size;}`